# What is the size of shared memory page?

Tags: linux, memory

On Linux, for each process, I can check /proc/PID/statm file.

It's numbers contain values of:

- Total program size, in kilobytes
- Size of memory portions, in kilobytes ??????
- Number of pages that are shared

Which is great, but how do I know how much is a page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a Linux god (by any means) but typically page sizes are 4Kb.  There's a `pagesize` command that should tell you what it is set to on your system.  This gives the output of the getpagesize() function.

Comment: Actually, there is only the POSIX getpagesize() *function*. I am not aware of a pagesize command on Linux.

Comment: Yeah, function (not method).  Thanks.  Brain on auto there.  Thought I remembered a pagesize command somewhere...  Maybe was on Solaris or HP-UX...

Comment: Thanks, wrote "program" : #include <stdio.h>
void main(){printf("%d\n",getpagesize());}


and it returned 4096. thank you.

Comment: Really? You could have saved yourself some trouble there. If you're not on something other that your average Intel / AMD machine, it's always the same...

Comment: @wzzrd - I feel really bad about assuming something that "happens on average, usually, nearly always".

Answer (score 0):

99% of the time a page is 4096 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

On most common hardware (like AMD64 and i386), a memory page is 4 kilobytes. If I remember correctly, Sparc and some other architectures can do bigger pages, like 8kb.